# Nextjs-fastapi deployment in vercel

Tags: deployment, fastapi, integration, vercel, next.js13

I’ve been dealing with deploying a nextjs project which has embedded a FastAPI backend.
As said by the docs, you can add your api by creating an api folder at the root level of your next js project (which I did) and then by setting up the proxy in the nextConfig.js by adding a rewrites function as you can see in the picture bellow, everything should be setup for me to deploy in vercel.

However at this point the project is working just in development mode in which I can even concurrently run both backend and Frontend just by using yarn dev and I can access both sides right away. Now, when deploying on vercel I can see the UI but I can’t get any response from the backend (always throwing me 404 not found).

I’ve found a project here  that I was following through but everything seems to be ok. Bellow I’m going to leave a screenshot of my folder structure and my package JSON hopping somebody that dealt with this already give me some hints. Thank you all in advance

[Rewrite function on nextConfig.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9d8V.png)

[folder structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IN3Y.png)

[package.JSON y comandos para ejecutar con concurrencia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GaEY.png)

To make sure nextjs would take the routes belonging to the files in the api folder an ‘/api/ prefix must be added like in ‘/api/hola’
[main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYK0h.png)

I tried by deleting the repo. Creating a separate one for the backend and cloning it into the nextjs project, I looked at the vercel docs for the proxy stuff with the rewrites function and nothing seems to be working.